# Typescript on .js file with vscode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Generally I want to write `.js` files with typescript instead of Flow. I configured the webpack to use `ts-loader` on js extension, and that works just fine. I use `checkJs` on tsconfig file and it check the js file fine.

However, VS Code shows an error the error on js files:

> Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.

[image: Screenshot of Error]

How can I make that error go away in VS Code?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use typescript type declarations in js files. (Even with checkJS enabled)

On JS files you have to use JSDoc annotations.

```
/** @type {number} */
var x;
```

Typescript would check these for you.

But I guess what you're looking for is a .ts file

Comment: Thanks for your response, I know that .ts get full IDE supports. But in js file I get full typescript support to with this configuration, the problem is vscode validate type annotation and expect it only for .ts files

Comment: Did you try the JS doc annotation . Doesnt that work for you?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you generally should use the correct file extension but you can force VS Code to treat JS files as TypeScript by [setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings):

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.js": "typescript"
}
```

Comment: This helps but VSCode restart is required, as specified by @jony89 answer and according to my experience

Answer (score 2):

Since Typescript 3 is out, and the work they have done allowing it to be combined with babel 7, it makes sense now for many programmers to have typescript in `.js` files.

Currently I have added the following vscode settings :

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.js": "typescript"
},
```

And restarted VSCode, and it works for me.

Hopefully vscode will provide a cleaner solution in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You should use .ts, not .js files for TypeScript code in order to get full IDE and other tooling support. The compiler will transform your .ts files into .js.

Comment: Thanks for your response,  I know that .ts get full IDE supports. But in js file I get full typescript support to with this configuration, the problem is vscode validate type annotation and expect it only for .ts files